# What #define identifiers are reserved to the preprocessor?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I thought I read once that a leading underscore in a `#define` value like;

```
#define _FOO
```

was discouraged or forbidden by ANSI C or some other standard.  Today I've combed the Internet, reviewed K&R and the CRM and can't find anything to support that.  The closest I've found is a suggestion (without suitable citation) that predefined identifiers always start *and* end with a double underscore so that the above will not conflict.  I ask because I'm using a new static checker that is complaining about:

```
#ifndef __FOO_H
#define __FOO_H
...
#endif // __FOO_H
```

at the `#define` line and I can't find an authoritative answer whether I'm right or the checker is.

Comment: *"Today I've combed the Internet, reviewed K&R and the CRM and can't find anything to support that"* - Ummm... did you try the standard?

Comment: Yeah, that.  :)  The standard is basically the most authoritative document you'll find re: what is and isn't well-formed C code.

Comment: I don't have a printed one and didn't find it online.  Likely my search terms were weak.  I'd have sworn "C standard" or "ANSI C" or "C99" were in there somewhere, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Today I've combed the Internet, reviewed K&R and the CRM and can't find anything to support that.*

> (C99, 7.1.3.p1) "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use."

Now regarding K&R book 2nd edition it is written:

> (K&R 2nd edition, 2.1) "Don't begin variable names with underscore, however, since library routines often use such names."

And if CRM actually refers to  CARM (C A Reference Manual by Harbison & Steele):

> (CARM 5th edition, 10.1.1 Reserved Library Identifiers): "The identifiers that are reserved for C implementations to use include: [...] for macros, keywords, or global
>       variables, identifiers beginning with _ and and either a second _ or an
>       uppercase letter (except _ _ STDC_...)"